# How do i iterate through a list of floats and assign them into variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of floats as such:

```
list_of_numbers = [6.983508046396359, 3.1427777550591887, -24.42539243473745]
```

I wish to assign the list of floats into individual variables as such

```
w1 = 6.983508046396359
w2 = 3.1427777550591887
w3 = -24.42539243473745
```

How do i go about assigning them into the desired variables?

Comment: Why do you want them in variables? Variable count is predefined when writing the code. Lists or other data structures can expand as needed.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to do this. You want a dictionary. Having names floating around in the namespace is, at best, impractical.

Comment: give a look at Python unpacking feature

Comment: really just want to retrieve the value... not for any other purpose

Answer (score 2):

Use [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

```
list_of_numbers = [6.983508046396359, 3.1427777550591887, -24.42539243473745]
w1, w2, w3 = list_of_numbers
```

If you have a variable number of variables, consider using a dictionary:

```
w = dict(enumerate(list_of_numbers, 1))
```

Then access, for example, the first float via `w[1]`.

Comment: Beat me by 11 seconds...

Comment: thanks for the answer it is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dictionary:

```
list_of_numbers = [6.983508046396359, 3.1427777550591887, -24.42539243473745]
d = {"w" + str(i+1): j for i,j in enumerate(list_of_numbers)}
```

This can be accessed thus:

```
d["w1"]
>>> 6.983508046396359
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there will always be the same number of values, then unpacking is a good option:

```
w1, w2, w3 = list_of_numbers
```

If, on the other hand, you want to do this for arbitrary length lists of numbers, then I would suggest that you are taking the wrong approach. If you must name them, use a dictionary like @ukemi suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If the number and the names of the variables is known, unpacking is enough:

```
w1, w2, w3 = list_of_numbers
```

If you pass a list longuer than the number of variables, last one will receive a sequence containing the unexpanded list of all remaining elements from the field, if the list is too short, you will get an exception.

If the number and the names of the variables is not known in advance, then you do not want to do that. It is certainly possible because Python if dynamic enough, but is is hard to build and to use when direct access to a list is much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

if you've a small list

```
w1 = list_of_numbers[0]
w2 = list_of_numbers[1]
w3 = list_of_numbers[2]
```

Comment: And if they don't have a "small" list?

Comment: For a predefined set of variables, i think this will do. Also it always depends on what you're actually trying to achieve

Comment: For a predefined set of variables, one should use unpacking: `w1, w2, w3 = list_of_numbers`